# Batch File To List All Movie Files In Sub-Folders Named #, A, B, C, D, thru Z

Tags: batch-file

I used to be pretty good with batch files many years ago, but I never learned how to do FOR loops.  From looking at other examples, I think I am on the right path, but I'm having trouble grasping how to do it exactly.

Here is my working batch file, just that it only results in the very last sub-folder (the Z folder in my case) being listed, because I do not know how to utilize just one line at a time from the "folders.txt" file:

```
@echo off

echo - - -  LIST GENERATED: %DATE%  - - - >  "- MOVIELIST.TXT"

dir /B /A:D >folders.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (folders.txt) do set FOLDER=%%a

:BUILD_LIST
echo. >> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
echo - - - - - - -  %FOLDER%  - - - - - - - >> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
echo. >> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
dir %FOLDER%/OGNS /B >> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"

:END
del "folders.txt"
set FOLDER=
start notepad "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
exit
```

Comment: _"I used to be pretty good with batch files many years ago, but I never learned how to do FOR loops"_  **`<-`**  This is a contradiction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to redirect the output of `dir` to `folders.txt`. Just use the `FOR` command to do it for you.

You can also make use of parenthesis to minimize the use of `>> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"`

So,

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:D') DO (
   (
      echo.
      echo - - - - - - -  %%a  - - - - - - - 
      echo. 
      dir %%a/OGNS /B 
   )>> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
)
```

you could also include your previous `ECHO` inside:

```
@echo off
(
    echo - - -  LIST GENERATED: %DATE%  - - - 
    FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:D') DO (
      echo.
      echo - - - - - - -  %%a  - - - - - - - 
      echo. 
      dir %%a/OGNS /B
    )
)> "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
```

Alternatively, use this 
**EDIT** suggested by Squashman:
`FOR /D`

```
FOR /D %%a in (*) DO (
   echo.
   echo - - - - - - -  %%a  - - - - - - - 
   echo. 
      dir %%a/OGNS /B 
)
```

`HELP` information:

> FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
>     names instead of file names.

Note that all variables are expanded before the parenthesis is executed because it is treated as one command

then after that you continue with your `:END`

```
:END
start notepad "- MOVIELIST.TXT"
exit
```

here it isn't necessary to use `%FOLDER%` and `folders.txt`

Comment: Wow!  So elegant!  Thank you soooooo much!

Comment: Why not use FOR /D?

Comment: I guess the other method allows for further modification of your `DIR` command